# How can I add a static library and pthread to a Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

All those files in the same folder:
AES.c, cryptlib.h and the static library libcl.a

I would like to write a Makefile which add the pthread and the static library but I don't know where and how I should do it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point. I would answer your real questions, **if** you would tell us where you are stuck at :)

```
all: myapp

LDFLAGS+=libcl.a
LDFLAGS+= -lpthread

myapp: AES.c libcl.a
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

myapp: cryptlib.h
```

I hate hardcoding dependencies for C/C++ projects; If you're like me you can consider something like (assuming gcc style options...):

```
all: myapp

LDFLAGS+=libcl.a
LDFLAGS+= -lpthread

myapp: AES.o libcl.a
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.depend: *.c
    $(CC) -M $< > $@

-include .depend
```

Comment: Why the order-only prerequisites? Certainly, if the header or library are updated, you would want the target to be updated as well.

Comment: Is that how that worked? Ok I must have been recalling that wrong, updating answer in a minute :)